# IDE Fatal Erors

Tags: linux, android-studio

My Android Studio gives me this fatal error.
So Far, I did ivalidated cache, I restored to default settings, I even configured VM acceleration but nothing worked.
I also getting **syntax highlighting has been temporarily turned off because of an internal error** in my mainActivity.kt, and it doesn't show any preview despite the @Preview tag.
The stacktrace is as follows:

````
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeScreenComponentFactory.lambda$createEventLink$1(WelcomeScreenComponentFactory.java:303)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeMethod(MessageBusImpl.java:645)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeListener(MessageBusImpl.java:624)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:417)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpWaitingBuses(MessageBusImpl.java:390)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:372)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:33)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$MessagePublisher.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.notificationsChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeBalloonLayoutImpl.updatePopup(WelcomeBalloonLayoutImpl.java:181)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeBalloonLayoutImpl$3.dispose(WelcomeBalloonLayoutImpl.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectTree.runWithTrace(ObjectTree.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectTree.executeAll(ObjectTree.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:217)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:205)
    at com.intellij.ui.BalloonLayoutImpl.dispose(BalloonLayoutImpl.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeBalloonLayoutImpl.dispose(WelcomeBalloonLayoutImpl.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectTree.runWithTrace(ObjectTree.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectTree.executeAll(ObjectTree.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:217)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:205)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrame.dispose(FlatWelcomeFrame.java:232)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectTree.runWithTrace(ObjectTree.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectTree.executeAll(ObjectTree.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:217)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:205)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrame$1.projectOpened(FlatWelcomeFrame.java:124)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeMethod(MessageBusImpl.java:645)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.invokeListener(MessageBusImpl.java:624)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$300(MessageBusImpl.java:33)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$MessagePublisher.executeOrAddToQueue(MessageBusImpl.java:208)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.CompositeMessageBus$ToDirectChildrenMessagePublisher.publish(CompositeMessageBus.java:105)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$MessagePublisher.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.projectOpened(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImplKt$openProject$1.run(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:468)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:214)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$200(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:196)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeAndWait$7(ApplicationImpl.java:450)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:134)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:82)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:131)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:47)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:187)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:891)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:760)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:818)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:492)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.pumpEventsForHierarchy(IdeEventQueue.java:951)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.lambda$startBlocking$6(ProgressWindow.java:221)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runUnlockingIntendedWrite(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:217)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$execFromEDT$6(ProgressRunner.java:321)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.execFromEDT(ProgressRunner.java:318)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.submit(ProgressRunner.java:259)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.submitAndGet(ProgressRunner.java:185)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectUiFrameAllocator.run(ProjectFrameAllocator.kt:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl.doOpenAsync(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl.openProjectAsync(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:110)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerExImpl.openProject(ProjectManagerExImpl.kt:72)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtil.tryOpenOrImport(ProjectUtil.java:172)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtil.openOrImport(ProjectUtil.java:131)
    at com.intellij.ide.impl.ProjectUtil.openOrImport(ProjectUtil.java:127)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidOpenFileAction.openOrImportProject(AndroidOpenFileAction.java:179)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidOpenFileAction.doOpenFile(AndroidOpenFileAction.java:149)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidOpenFileAction.lambda$actionPerformed$0(AndroidOpenFileAction.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.ex.FileChooserDialogImpl.choose(FileChooserDialogImpl.java:146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.FileChooser.chooseFiles(FileChooser.java:102)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.FileChooser.chooseFiles(FileChooser.java:80)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidOpenFileAction.actionPerformed(AndroidOpenFileAction.java:101)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:239)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:260)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:239)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeScreenActionsUtil.performAnActionForComponent(WelcomeScreenActionsUtil.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeScreenActionsUtil$LargeIconWithTextWrapper.lambda$new$0(WelcomeScreenActionsUtil.java:125)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:270)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6654)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2790)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:891)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:820)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:757)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:818)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:498)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)```
````

Comment: You are trying to debug your IDE? If you figure out what's wrong are you going to rebuild it? Delete it and use a different one or a working version.

Comment: I don't actually. I have another Linux machine which I tried to install Android Studio. Compose previews doesn't work, and I get this interesting error message in logs. Have no clue.

Answer (score -1):

What happens on line 303 of WelcomeScreenComponentFactory.java:303 ?

In general a NPE or null pointer exception happens when you attempt to reference a method or property of an variable in code and that variable is not initialized or is pointing at null.  if on line 303 you have someObject.someMethod() then can infer that someObject was null when the line was run.  Sounds like when you're calling that library method the object being passed to it is null, but can maybe run in debug mode and step back through the stack trace to see what call/setup your app made before the exception is thrown as well.

Comment: I don't run any programs, it's a IDE bug.